# Regex that supports all languages

Tags: php, json, regex

I have a regex which works good on ANSI characters:

```
$foo = preg_replace('!(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i', "<a href='$1' style='somestyling''>$1</a>", $bar);
```

But if I have a url like `http://www.example.com/sometextć` I get the result

`www.example.com/sometext��`where � is %uFFFD.

I would really like it to work on all characters if there is any solution. If not, I would gladly want to get rid of � since it cannot be json encoded.

Comment: You may need to use `\pL` to accept all letters from all languages. It includes accentuated letters.

Comment: in your `[ ]` you could add every unicode char using `[\u0000-\uFFFF]`

Comment: @Niitaku Add where? I have tried it adding to the end, but no success. I don't really understand regex quite well.

Comment: You can try changing your character set to this `[-\pL()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;\/=]`. I also corrected in it the slash (`/`) escape.

Comment: @Niitaku Nope, still the same.